# Why do results vary based on curly brace placement?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Why do the code snippets below, taken from [this article](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/16/beware-of-javascript-semicolon-insertion/), produce different results due to only a single change in the placement of curly braces?

When the opening curly brace `{` is on a new line, `test()` returns `undefined`, and "no - it broke: undefined" is displayed in the alert.

```js
function test()
{
  return
  { /* <--- curly brace on new line */
    javascript: "fantastic"
  };
}

var r = test();
try {
  alert(r.javascript); // does this work...?
} catch (e) {
  alert('no - it broke: ' + typeof r);
}
```

When the brace is on the same line as `return`, `test()` returns an object, and "fantastic" is alerted.

```js
function test()
{
  return { /* <---- curly brace on same line */
    javascript: "fantastic"
  };
}

var r = test();
try {
  alert(r.javascript); // does this work...?
} catch (e) {
  alert('no - it broke: ' + typeof r);
}
```

Comment: the semi-insertion semantics after `return` are slightly different than in other places, and a line break "means more" in that spot than it would "midstream".

Comment: In simple whatever you write next line of return will be ignored by javascript.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

That's one of the pitfalls of JavaScript: automatic semicolon insertion. Lines that do not end with a semicolon, but could be the end of a statement, are automatically terminated, so your first example looks effectively like this:

```
function test()
{
  return; // <- notice the inserted semicolon
  { 
    javascript: "fantastic"
  };
}
```

See also [Douglas Crockford's JS style guide](https://www.crockford.com/code.html), which mentions semicolon insertion.

In your second example you return an object (built by the curly braces) with the property `javascript` and its value of `"fantastic"`, effectively the same as this:

```
function test() {
    var myObject = new Object();
    myObject.javascript = "fantastic";
    return myObject;
}
```

Comment: Exactly right. Crockford has a googletalk video on youtube where he illustrates this very clearly.

Comment: Fun Fact: On some engines you can comment out the auto-inserted semicolons

Comment: @ChrisT: What? Which ones? Is this explored anywhere?

Comment: @SeanMcMillan I've definetly read articles about it but I can't seem to find any of them from a quick search. I remember that putting `return /*` and then `*/{ ` would effectively comment out the hidden semi-colon in older versions of chrome. Not sure if that still applies

Comment: Because of these quirks I made a promise to myself 10 years ago: stay away from the web! I prayed that the Interwebs would fade away... Unfortunately it didn't go as planned, and now I have to struggle with these issues as well. Karma is a b*tch :)

Comment: Here's another example of an issue:
```BB.promisifyAll(myFs);

// name the anon function
(async myReadFileAsync => {
    const contents = await myFs.readFileAsync('filename.txt')
    console.log('promisifyAll: ', contents)
})()```

Without the `;` it will try to execute the return from `BB.promisifyAll(myFs)` which is not what I intended.

Comment: I've seen people that are religiously against semicolons in JavaScript, I've always wondered what do they do with that extra time they save by not putting semicolons.

Answer (score 15):

Javascript doesn't require semicolons at the end of statements, but the drawback is that it has to guess where the semicolons are. Most of the time this is not a problem, but sometimes it invents a semicolon where you didn't intend one.

If you format the code like this:

```
function getAnswer() {
   var answer = 42;
   return
      answer;
}
```

Then it is interpreted like this:

```
function getAnswer() {
  var answer = 42;
  return;
  answer;
}
```

The return statement takes its parameterless form, and the argument becomes a statement of its own.

The same happens to your code. The function is interpreted as:

```
function test()
{
  return;
  {
    javascript : "fantastic"
  };
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I personally prefer the Allman Style for readability (vs K&R style).

Instead of…

```
function test() {
  return {
    javascript : "fantastic"
  };
}
```

I like…

```
function test() 
{
  var obj =
  {
    javascript : "fantastic"
  };

  return obj;
}
```

But this is a work-around.  I can live with it though.

Comment: I think we should avoid personal preferences that deviate from the mainstream. We should follow the choices of the majority, which promotes consistency, which will increase readability

Comment: I find his code more readable than the K&R. Pretty subjective when you mean "readable"

Comment: I prefer the Allman too... but due to ASI, when I need to return an object, I leave the semi on the same line as the return. I prefer this than to add one "var x= " line...

Comment: Allman style looks like bloat to me. sonarlint would flag this unnecesarry variable decrlation as code smell.

Answer (score 2):

It's because javascript most often puts ";" at the end of each line, so basicly when you have return { in same line, javascript engine see that there will be something more, and when its in new line it thinks you forgot to put ";", and puts it for you.

Comment: I don't get why cichy's, Darin's and Ivo's answers were downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

The curly braces here indicate the construction of a new object. Thus your code is equivalent to:

```
function test() {
  var a = { javascript : "fantastic" };
  return a;
}
```

which works whereas if you write:

```
function test() {
  var a = { javascript : "fantastic" };
  return; // ; is automatically inserted 
      a;
}
```

it no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed semicolon injection as described above. I just read a good blog posting on this subject. It explains this issue and a whole lot more about javascript. It also contains some good references. You can read it [here](http://skilldrick.co.uk/2010/09/why-javascript-is-awesome/)

Comment: Yes, i also read that, ater reading i asks here to explain better by mastermind of js.