# Alignment issues in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying some simple javascript and what I discovered is quite amazing if you ask me, I was wondering why javascript behaves like this.
So I have a simple inline function that defines two inner functions: task 1 and task2, and has a return object with two properties: job1 and job2, where job1 points to task1 and job2 points to task2. I get an error like:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

and the amazing part is that if I move the curly brace immediately after the return statement (see comment in code), the script actually works and prompts an alert "1" as expected. Why does it matter if I put the curly brace immediately after return or on the next line?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.17/angular2.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

var x = function()
{
    var task1 = function() { alert("1"); }
    var task2 = function() { alert("2"); }

    return 
    { ///////////// move this on the previous line right after return
        job1: task1,
        job2: task2
    };
}

x().job1();

</script>
```

I always thought that in javascript this:

```
var x = function() {
//content
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
var x = function() 
{
//content
}
```

but obviously not in the case I mentioned first. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript function fails to return object when there is a line-break between the return statement and the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221963/javascript-function-fails-to-return-object-when-there-is-a-line-break-between-th)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Automatic_Semicolon_Insertion

Comment: further reading  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528557/why-doesnt-a-javascript-return-statement-work-when-the-return-value-is-on-a-new

Comment: Please see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960518/javascript-formatting-must-braces-be-on-the-same-line-as-the-if-function-etc-ke) on the StackOverflow forum :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does it matter if I put the curly brace immediately after return or on the next line?

Because semi-colons are optional in javascript.  The parser does some "magic" to determine where the end of statement is and sees `return<newline>` as the equivalent of `return;`.