# Are there any hidden code formatting settings for Javascript in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, formatting, settings, code-formatting, netbeans-6.9

I do PHP/Javascript development in NetBeans, and I really like the environment, except for one thing - in Javascript, when I press ENTER after a statement, and type the opening brace, it is indented. Like this:

```
if ( a == b )
    {}
```

I want the brace to stay on the same level, like this:

```
if ( a == b )
{}
```

So that when I press ENTER again, I'd get this:

```
if ( a == b )
{

}
```

Can this be done and how?

Comment: I also seek a solution to javascript formatting for javascript on netbeans 7.x but I'm  too thrifty to start a bounty for it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't have the answer to your question. I too have searched in vain for somewhere in NetBeans 6 to configure JavaScript formatting.

However, you should note the following:
In languages like Java it's legitimate to choose between opening brace on the same line vs. opening brace on a newline. In JavaScript, however, you should really stick to the former as the latter can give rise to ambiguities that can affect the interpretation of the code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641519/why-results-varies-upon-placement-of-curly-braces-in-javascript-code). (I know the example you cite relates to the *if* statement, but presumably you want to be consistent.)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this, but in most cases it presents no problems, so I'd like a consistent formatting in all my code.

Answer (score 1):

Great news for netbeans devotes here: (netbeans 7.0)

```
Tools -> Options > Editor > Code Templates: choose Language (Javascript in this case)
```

Look for "**if**" Abbreviation:

Change *Expanded text* definition:

from this:

> ```
> if (${expr}){
>     ${cursor}
> }
> ```

to this:

> ```
> if (${expr})
> {
>     ${cursor}
> }
> ```

Save options.

Now inside a js file type **if** and press **[tab]**... and you got it...

Can you imagine all possibilities with these templates?

Comment: Cute, but not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Vilx Yes, is not exactly the same, but are you tried?. You just push 3 keys and cursor is positioned to enter the argument and braces are positioned as you want. You can change [tab] to [enter] with "Expand Template on" at the bottom of the options window!

Comment: I'd like to adapt my IDE to my typing habits, instead of adapting my typing habits to my IDE.

Comment: All wants the same. Look, I arrived to this topic looking for a solution for exactly the same problem you say. I have another one: make a code template with just 2 braces opened and assign it to one key (in my case is _ (spanish keyboard) that is near to [Enter] key). So now with just 2 keystrokes I have braces opened to the left margin! If that is not adapt the IDE I don't know what more can be. Ie: just delete `if (${expr})` in the _Expanded text_ definition I showed.