# How do I optimize this Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, algorithm, event-handling

I have a procedure so that my top nav has a different style if the user is scrolled near the top of the page or farther down from:

```
/* Handle the changing of the top nav on page scroll */
window.onscroll = function ()
{
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 150) // 150 pixels from top triggers scrolling
    {
        $('.navbar-default').addClass('scrolling');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.navbar-default').removeClass('scrolling');
    }
};
```

The problem is that I realize this is efficient because `class` of `navbar-default` is being added or removed a small number of times with respect to the number of times that `onscroll` is invoked. I also realized that I need to change an image in the nav depending on whether or not scrolling is happening, so I would then have essentially

```
/* Handle the changing of the top nav on page scroll */
window.onscroll = function ()
{
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 150) // 150 pixels from top triggers scrolling
    {
        $('.navbar-default').addClass('scrolling');
        $('.navbar-default .navvar-brand img').attr('src','image1.jpg');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.navbar-default').removeClass('scrolling');
        $('.navbar-default .navvar-brand img').attr('src','image2.jpg');
    }
};
```

which is even more ridiculous. How can I fumigate this room full of code smell?

Comment: The title of this question is very confusing.

Comment: @Pointy I mean how do I reduce the average number of operations

Comment: So, "how" and not "why" ...

Comment: No the question is both why and how. `.addClass()` probably checks `hasClass()` first, so as not to rewrite HTML, so that shouldn't be an issue. As for the second point, use CSS rather than an img tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

- Place your curly braces on the same line as the function or you may run into situational problems with automatic semi colon insertion - [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641519/why-does-a-results-vary-based-on-curly-brace-placement)
- Use a sprite for the image instead - [Tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)
- Toggle the class
- Use css to change the toggle between images instead of changing the img source based on the class of the `nav-default`

  ```
  // Something like this...
  .nav-default {
    background-image: url('spriteimage.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: // height of first image here;
    background-position: // position of first image here;
  }

  .nav-default.scrolling {
    height: // height of second image here;
    background-position: // position of second image here;
  }
  ```

More advanced possibilities:

*(I don't personally know if this boosts performance but you could try it)*

- Poll at a small interval (100ms) to check for the position of the scroll bar as opposed to checking every single time someone scrolls and then toggle the class
- This will be less quick/responsive but will be more consistent (worst case: toggle the class every 100ms)